# iScroll 4 horizontal mousewheel scroll

Tags: html, css, jquery-plugins, horizontal-scrolling, iscroll

I'm using iScroll 4 but mousewheel scroll is not working even though I've put the parameter for `wheelAction: 'scroll'`

Here's my **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iamthestig/2cMNu/)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After searching for 5 hours, found it on iScroll 4 github.

They just added a mousewheel horizontal scroll support 5 days ago. Not as fancy as the drag and slide with momentum but it will do. Maybe after some mods I'll add some momentum to it.

Here's my update **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iamthestig/2cMNu/6/)**